# Intel x550 NIC rx_dropped packet on Debian 10

Tags: debian, intel

I have just added an Intel x550T2 10Gb NIC on my Debian 10 server, and noticed that I have a lot of rx_dropped errors. The card is on a correct PCIe extension slot (PCIe3.0 x8).
At the moment, it is linked to a 1Gb switch which run perfect with the native onboard Intel i210 NICs. No drop or error on those ones.

Here is some info for the i210 NIC :

```
# ethtool -i enp35s0
driver: igb
version: 5.10.0-0.bpo.9-amd64
firmware-version: 3.16, 0x800004d6
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:23:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

And for the x550 NIC now:

```
# ethtool -i enp1s0f0
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.10.0-0.bpo.9-amd64
firmware-version: 0x80000c67, 1.1276.0
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

# ethtool -S enp1s0f0 | grep rx_dropped
  rx_dropped: 238664

# ifconfig -a
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether b4:96:91:8d:8f:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1146605303  bytes 1252350638244 (1.1 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 239154  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1237206229  bytes 1474837845271 (1.3 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp35s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:50:99:d8:dd:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 128548674  bytes 92790323605 (86.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4654  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 310482004  bytes 401876909266 (374.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7500000-f757ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2768489  bytes 43506238580 (40.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2768489  bytes 43506238580 (40.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have already tried to max the buffer ring but still have the error:

```
# ethtool -g enp1s0f0
Ring parameters for enp1s0f0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             1024
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             1024

# ethtool -G enp1s0f0 rx 4096 tx 4096

# ethtool -g enp1s0f0
Ring parameters for enp1s0f0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
```

OK... more tests.

I just plugged both second i210 and x550 NIC with some other cables to the switch (Netgear GS108e).

Done some iPerf tests with all the NICs...

```
Connecting to host 192.168.1.100, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.31 port 63926 connected to 192.168.1.100 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   111 MBytes   928 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   109 MBytes   911 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   108 MBytes   904 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   110 MBytes   919 Mbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec   112 MBytes   937 Mbits/sec
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-19.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec  2.18 GBytes   935 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec  2.18 GBytes   935 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

```
Connecting to host 192.168.1.200, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.31 port 63921 connected to 192.168.1.200 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   111 MBytes   930 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   937 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   109 MBytes   914 Mbits/sec
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-19.00  sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec  2.18 GBytes   937 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec  2.18 GBytes   937 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Guest what ? There are drop packets on every NIC !

```
# ifconfig -a
enp1s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:96:91:8d:8f:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1151051611  bytes 1252669838122 (1.1 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 239910  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1255759988  bytes 1492773432922 (1.3 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:96:91:8d:8f:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1385  bytes 278792 (272.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 258  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 14914 (14.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp35s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether d0:50:99:d8:dd:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 163831215  bytes 103267767777 (96.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 8634  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 391577507  bytes 511527961464 (476.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7500000-f757ffff

enp36s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether d0:50:99:d8:dd:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1706  bytes 253758 (247.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 102  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 12656 (12.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7400000-f747ffff
```

So :

It's probably not the cables (all the cables are directly connected to the switch),
It's probably not the NICs, as 2 are on the motherboard (ASRock Rack x470D4U) and 2 are on the PCie x550T2 Card,
Switch ?
Server configuration... maybe/maybe not ?

Here is the result of the command asked. It drops 1 or 2 packets every second, under load or not. Don't think it's linked to the traffic. Just tried a tcpdump with wireshark but I'm don't know enough about network and packets to find those packets and where they come from

```
# ethtool -S enp1s0f0

NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 409237588
     tx_packets: 1075009015
     rx_bytes: 177473575288
     tx_bytes: 1263310826660
     rx_pkts_nic: 409228445
     tx_pkts_nic: 1074969396
     rx_bytes_nic: 179109854075
     tx_bytes_nic: 1267596999232
     lsc_int: 24
     tx_busy: 0
     non_eop_descs: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_dropped: 223170
     tx_dropped: 0
     multicast: 42561
     broadcast: 264995
     rx_no_buffer_count: 0
     collisions: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     hw_rsc_aggregated: 0
     hw_rsc_flushed: 0
     fdir_match: 317742293
     fdir_miss: 91206754
     fdir_overflow: 80
     rx_fifo_errors: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     tx_timeout_count: 0
     tx_restart_queue: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     tx_flow_control_xon: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 0
     tx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 3360
     alloc_rx_page: 3189180
     alloc_rx_page_failed: 0
     alloc_rx_buff_failed: 0
     rx_no_dma_resources: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_bmc: 0
     os2bmc_tx_by_bmc: 0
     os2bmc_tx_by_host: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_host: 0
     tx_hwtstamp_timeouts: 0
     tx_hwtstamp_skipped: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
     tx_ipsec: 0
     rx_ipsec: 0
     fcoe_bad_fccrc: 0
     rx_fcoe_dropped: 0
     rx_fcoe_packets: 0
     rx_fcoe_dwords: 0
     fcoe_noddp: 0
     fcoe_noddp_ext_buff: 0
     tx_fcoe_packets: 0
     tx_fcoe_dwords: 0
     tx_queue_0_packets: 74036009
     tx_queue_0_bytes: 88586204439
     tx_queue_1_packets: 80720857
     tx_queue_1_bytes: 95762098192
     tx_queue_2_packets: 79235034
     tx_queue_2_bytes: 94041578505
     tx_queue_3_packets: 123318040
     tx_queue_3_bytes: 137970928742
     tx_queue_4_packets: 106181552
     tx_queue_4_bytes: 123073004110
     tx_queue_5_packets: 99889184
     tx_queue_5_bytes: 116673367186
     tx_queue_6_packets: 78150254
     tx_queue_6_bytes: 93047598926
     tx_queue_7_packets: 75574096
     tx_queue_7_bytes: 89970346004
     tx_queue_8_packets: 69957159
     tx_queue_8_bytes: 83610931698
     tx_queue_9_packets: 95301527
     tx_queue_9_bytes: 112400389659
     tx_queue_10_packets: 95414279
     tx_queue_10_bytes: 112725481253
     tx_queue_11_packets: 97231024
     tx_queue_11_bytes: 115448897946
     tx_queue_12_packets: 0
     tx_queue_12_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_13_packets: 0
     tx_queue_13_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_14_packets: 0
     tx_queue_14_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_15_packets: 0
     tx_queue_15_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_16_packets: 0
     tx_queue_16_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_17_packets: 0
     tx_queue_17_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_18_packets: 0
     tx_queue_18_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_19_packets: 0
     tx_queue_19_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_20_packets: 0
     tx_queue_20_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_21_packets: 0
     tx_queue_21_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_22_packets: 0
     tx_queue_22_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_23_packets: 0
     tx_queue_23_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_24_packets: 0
     tx_queue_24_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_25_packets: 0
     tx_queue_25_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_26_packets: 0
     tx_queue_26_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_27_packets: 0
     tx_queue_27_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_28_packets: 0
     tx_queue_28_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_29_packets: 0
     tx_queue_29_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_30_packets: 0
     tx_queue_30_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_31_packets: 0
     tx_queue_31_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_32_packets: 0
     tx_queue_32_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_33_packets: 0
     tx_queue_33_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_34_packets: 0
     tx_queue_34_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_35_packets: 0
     tx_queue_35_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_36_packets: 0
     tx_queue_36_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_37_packets: 0
     tx_queue_37_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_38_packets: 0
     tx_queue_38_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_39_packets: 0
     tx_queue_39_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_40_packets: 0
     tx_queue_40_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_41_packets: 0
     tx_queue_41_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_42_packets: 0
     tx_queue_42_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_43_packets: 0
     tx_queue_43_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_44_packets: 0
     tx_queue_44_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_45_packets: 0
     tx_queue_45_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_46_packets: 0
     tx_queue_46_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_47_packets: 0
     tx_queue_47_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_48_packets: 0
     tx_queue_48_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_49_packets: 0
     tx_queue_49_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_50_packets: 0
     tx_queue_50_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_51_packets: 0
     tx_queue_51_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_52_packets: 0
     tx_queue_52_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_53_packets: 0
     tx_queue_53_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_54_packets: 0
     tx_queue_54_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_55_packets: 0
     tx_queue_55_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_56_packets: 0
     tx_queue_56_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_57_packets: 0
     tx_queue_57_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_58_packets: 0
     tx_queue_58_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_59_packets: 0
     tx_queue_59_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_60_packets: 0
     tx_queue_60_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_61_packets: 0
     tx_queue_61_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_62_packets: 0
     tx_queue_62_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_63_packets: 0
     tx_queue_63_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_0_packets: 29057648
     rx_queue_0_bytes: 13104849941
     rx_queue_1_packets: 26822820
     rx_queue_1_bytes: 11818472270
     rx_queue_2_packets: 26597646
     rx_queue_2_bytes: 10723639020
     rx_queue_3_packets: 60978762
     rx_queue_3_bytes: 20890319775
     rx_queue_4_packets: 33801309
     rx_queue_4_bytes: 16858301557
     rx_queue_5_packets: 34807507
     rx_queue_5_bytes: 17466548842
     rx_queue_6_packets: 32378144
     rx_queue_6_bytes: 12435614922
     rx_queue_7_packets: 32146268
     rx_queue_7_bytes: 11553792114
     rx_queue_8_packets: 25931411
     rx_queue_8_bytes: 11173658863
     rx_queue_9_packets: 37015008
     rx_queue_9_bytes: 19310784393
     rx_queue_10_packets: 33071252
     rx_queue_10_bytes: 16248791562
     rx_queue_11_packets: 36629813
     rx_queue_11_bytes: 15888802029
     rx_queue_12_packets: 0
     rx_queue_12_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_13_packets: 0
     rx_queue_13_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_14_packets: 0
     rx_queue_14_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_15_packets: 0
     rx_queue_15_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_16_packets: 0
     rx_queue_16_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_17_packets: 0
     rx_queue_17_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_18_packets: 0
     rx_queue_18_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_19_packets: 0
     rx_queue_19_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_20_packets: 0
     rx_queue_20_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_21_packets: 0
     rx_queue_21_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_22_packets: 0
     rx_queue_22_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_23_packets: 0
     rx_queue_23_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_24_packets: 0
     rx_queue_24_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_25_packets: 0
     rx_queue_25_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_26_packets: 0
     rx_queue_26_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_27_packets: 0
     rx_queue_27_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_28_packets: 0
     rx_queue_28_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_29_packets: 0
     rx_queue_29_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_30_packets: 0
     rx_queue_30_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_31_packets: 0
     rx_queue_31_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_32_packets: 0
     rx_queue_32_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_33_packets: 0
     rx_queue_33_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_34_packets: 0
     rx_queue_34_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_35_packets: 0
     rx_queue_35_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_36_packets: 0
     rx_queue_36_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_37_packets: 0
     rx_queue_37_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_38_packets: 0
     rx_queue_38_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_39_packets: 0
     rx_queue_39_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_40_packets: 0
     rx_queue_40_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_41_packets: 0
     rx_queue_41_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_42_packets: 0
     rx_queue_42_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_43_packets: 0
     rx_queue_43_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_44_packets: 0
     rx_queue_44_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_45_packets: 0
     rx_queue_45_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_46_packets: 0
     rx_queue_46_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_47_packets: 0
     rx_queue_47_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_48_packets: 0
     rx_queue_48_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_49_packets: 0
     rx_queue_49_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_50_packets: 0
     rx_queue_50_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_51_packets: 0
     rx_queue_51_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_52_packets: 0
     rx_queue_52_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_53_packets: 0
     rx_queue_53_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_54_packets: 0
     rx_queue_54_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_55_packets: 0
     rx_queue_55_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_56_packets: 0
     rx_queue_56_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_57_packets: 0
     rx_queue_57_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_58_packets: 0
     rx_queue_58_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_59_packets: 0
     rx_queue_59_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_60_packets: 0
     rx_queue_60_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_61_packets: 0
     rx_queue_61_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_62_packets: 0
     rx_queue_62_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_63_packets: 0
     rx_queue_63_bytes: 0
     tx_pb_0_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_0_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_1_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_1_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_2_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_2_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_3_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_3_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_4_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_4_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_5_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_5_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_6_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_6_pxoff: 0
     tx_pb_7_pxon: 0
     tx_pb_7_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_0_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_0_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_1_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_1_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_2_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_2_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_3_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_3_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_4_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_4_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_5_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_5_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_6_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_6_pxoff: 0
     rx_pb_7_pxon: 0
     rx_pb_7_pxoff: 0
```

To complete, I've tried the 'ethtool -d' command 2 times within 10s, and diff the results.

```
# ethtool -d enp1s0f0 > /tmp/dump1.log
# ethtool -d enp1s0f0 > /tmp/dump2.log
# diff /tmp/dump1.log /tmp/dump2.log
34c34
< 0x00048: FRTIMER     (Free Running Timer)             0x6E89EE7A
---

> 0x00048: FRTIMER     (Free Running Timer)             0x6F24AD04
47c47
< 0x00808: EICS        (Extended Interrupt Cause Set)   0x00000000
---
> 0x00808: EICS        (Extended Interrupt Cause Set)   0x00000010
52c52
< 0x00820: EITR0       (Extended Interrupt Throttle 0)  0x00000038
---
> 0x00820: EITR0       (Extended Interrupt Throttle 0)  0x00000028
272,283c272,283
< 0x01010: RDH00       (Receive Descriptor Head 00)     0x000002AA
< 0x01050: RDH01       (Receive Descriptor Head 01)     0x0000015B
< 0x01090: RDH02       (Receive Descriptor Head 02)     0x000003BE
< 0x010D0: RDH03       (Receive Descriptor Head 03)     0x00000227
< 0x01110: RDH04       (Receive Descriptor Head 04)     0x000000F9
< 0x01150: RDH05       (Receive Descriptor Head 05)     0x00000376
< 0x01190: RDH06       (Receive Descriptor Head 06)     0x000000DD
< 0x011D0: RDH07       (Receive Descriptor Head 07)     0x0000027D
< 0x01210: RDH08       (Receive Descriptor Head 08)     0x00000005
< 0x01250: RDH09       (Receive Descriptor Head 09)     0x000003B7
< 0x01290: RDH10       (Receive Descriptor Head 10)     0x0000015F
< 0x012D0: RDH11       (Receive Descriptor Head 11)     0x00000269
---
> 0x01010: RDH00       (Receive Descriptor Head 00)     0x00000215
> 0x01050: RDH01       (Receive Descriptor Head 01)     0x000001A0
> 0x01090: RDH02       (Receive Descriptor Head 02)     0x00000031
> 0x010D0: RDH03       (Receive Descriptor Head 03)     0x000001F2
> 0x01110: RDH04       (Receive Descriptor Head 04)     0x000000F8
> 0x01150: RDH05       (Receive Descriptor Head 05)     0x00000199
> 0x01190: RDH06       (Receive Descriptor Head 06)     0x000001B8
> 0x011D0: RDH07       (Receive Descriptor Head 07)     0x000002A0
> 0x01210: RDH08       (Receive Descriptor Head 08)     0x000002ED
> 0x01250: RDH09       (Receive Descriptor Head 09)     0x00000173
> 0x01290: RDH10       (Receive Descriptor Head 10)     0x000001A5
> 0x012D0: RDH11       (Receive Descriptor Head 11)     0x0000029D
336,339c336,339
< 0x01018: RDT00       (Receive Descriptor Tail 00)     0x0000029F
< 0x01058: RDT01       (Receive Descriptor Tail 01)     0x0000014F
< 0x01098: RDT02       (Receive Descriptor Tail 02)     0x000003AF
< 0x010D8: RDT03       (Receive Descriptor Tail 03)     0x0000021F
---
> 0x01018: RDT00       (Receive Descriptor Tail 00)     0x0000020F
> 0x01058: RDT01       (Receive Descriptor Tail 01)     0x0000019F
> 0x01098: RDT02       (Receive Descriptor Tail 02)     0x0000002F
> 0x010D8: RDT03       (Receive Descriptor Tail 03)     0x000001EF
341,347c341,347
< 0x01158: RDT05       (Receive Descriptor Tail 05)     0x0000036F
< 0x01198: RDT06       (Receive Descriptor Tail 06)     0x000000CF
< 0x011D8: RDT07       (Receive Descriptor Tail 07)     0x0000026F
< 0x01218: RDT08       (Receive Descriptor Tail 08)     0x000003FF
< 0x01258: RDT09       (Receive Descriptor Tail 09)     0x000003AF
< 0x01298: RDT10       (Receive Descriptor Tail 10)     0x0000014F
< 0x012D8: RDT11       (Receive Descriptor Tail 11)     0x0000025F
---
> 0x01158: RDT05       (Receive Descriptor Tail 05)     0x0000018F
> 0x01198: RDT06       (Receive Descriptor Tail 06)     0x000001AF
> 0x011D8: RDT07       (Receive Descriptor Tail 07)     0x0000029F
> 0x01218: RDT08       (Receive Descriptor Tail 08)     0x000002DF
> 0x01258: RDT09       (Receive Descriptor Tail 09)     0x0000016F
> 0x01298: RDT10       (Receive Descriptor Tail 10)     0x0000019F
> 0x012D8: RDT11       (Receive Descriptor Tail 11)     0x0000028F
657,668c657,668
< 0x06010: TDH00       (Transmit Descriptor Head 00)    0x00000338
< 0x06050: TDH01       (Transmit Descriptor Head 01)    0x000003BD
< 0x06090: TDH02       (Transmit Descriptor Head 02)    0x0000030C
< 0x060D0: TDH03       (Transmit Descriptor Head 03)    0x00000272
< 0x06110: TDH04       (Transmit Descriptor Head 04)    0x000001B2
< 0x06150: TDH05       (Transmit Descriptor Head 05)    0x000002A7
< 0x06190: TDH06       (Transmit Descriptor Head 06)    0x00000323
< 0x061D0: TDH07       (Transmit Descriptor Head 07)    0x000003D9
< 0x06210: TDH08       (Transmit Descriptor Head 08)    0x000003F5
< 0x06250: TDH09       (Transmit Descriptor Head 09)    0x000003C1
< 0x06290: TDH10       (Transmit Descriptor Head 10)    0x000000BD
< 0x062D0: TDH11       (Transmit Descriptor Head 11)    0x000000FC
---
> 0x06010: TDH00       (Transmit Descriptor Head 00)    0x00000373
> 0x06050: TDH01       (Transmit Descriptor Head 01)    0x0000003D
> 0x06090: TDH02       (Transmit Descriptor Head 02)    0x00000088
> 0x060D0: TDH03       (Transmit Descriptor Head 03)    0x00000000
> 0x06110: TDH04       (Transmit Descriptor Head 04)    0x000000D0
> 0x06150: TDH05       (Transmit Descriptor Head 05)    0x00000337
> 0x06190: TDH06       (Transmit Descriptor Head 06)    0x000000B3
> 0x061D0: TDH07       (Transmit Descriptor Head 07)    0x00000010
> 0x06210: TDH08       (Transmit Descriptor Head 08)    0x00000041
> 0x06250: TDH09       (Transmit Descriptor Head 09)    0x0000003D
> 0x06290: TDH10       (Transmit Descriptor Head 10)    0x000000FD
> 0x062D0: TDH11       (Transmit Descriptor Head 11)    0x00000137
689,700c689,700
< 0x06018: TDT00       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 00)    0x00000338
< 0x06058: TDT01       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 01)    0x000003BD
< 0x06098: TDT02       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 02)    0x0000030C
< 0x060D8: TDT03       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 03)    0x00000272
< 0x06118: TDT04       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 04)    0x000001B2
< 0x06158: TDT05       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 05)    0x000002A7
< 0x06198: TDT06       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 06)    0x00000323
< 0x061D8: TDT07       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 07)    0x000003D9
< 0x06218: TDT08       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 08)    0x000003F5
< 0x06258: TDT09       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 09)    0x000003C1
< 0x06298: TDT10       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 10)    0x000000BD
< 0x062D8: TDT11       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 11)    0x000000FC
---
> 0x06018: TDT00       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 00)    0x00000373
> 0x06058: TDT01       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 01)    0x0000003D
> 0x06098: TDT02       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 02)    0x00000088
> 0x060D8: TDT03       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 03)    0x00000000
> 0x06118: TDT04       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 04)    0x000000D0
> 0x06158: TDT05       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 05)    0x00000337
> 0x06198: TDT06       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 06)    0x000000B3
> 0x061D8: TDT07       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 07)    0x00000010
> 0x06218: TDT08       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 08)    0x00000041
> 0x06258: TDT09       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 09)    0x0000003D
> 0x06298: TDT10       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 10)    0x000000FD
> 0x062D8: TDT11       (Transmit Descriptor Tail 11)    0x00000137
947,957c947,957
< 0x0405C: prc64       (Packets Received (64B) Count)   0x094266A4
< 0x04060: prc127      (Packets Rx (65-127B) Count)     0x0D5353E1
< 0x04064: prc255      (Packets Rx (128-255B) Count)    0x003E3D72
< 0x04068: prc511      (Packets Rx (256-511B) Count)    0x002280C3
< 0x0406C: prc1023     (Packets Rx (512-1023B) Count)   0x011AAE03
< 0x04070: prc1522     (Packets Rx (1024-Max) Count)    0x17947BDE
< 0x04074: gprc        (Good Packets Received Count)    0x2FA5A298
< 0x04078: bprc        (Broadcast Packets Rx Count)     0x00087B71
< 0x0407C: mprc        (Multicast Packets Rx Count)     0x00012C8B
< 0x04080: gptc        (Good Packets Transmitted Count) 0x5BE951AE
< 0x04088: gorcl       (Good Octets Rx Count Low)       0xE9CD4970
---
> 0x0405C: prc64       (Packets Received (64B) Count)   0x0942693B
> 0x04060: prc127      (Packets Rx (65-127B) Count)     0x0D5355F2
> 0x04064: prc255      (Packets Rx (128-255B) Count)    0x003E3DA3
> 0x04068: prc511      (Packets Rx (256-511B) Count)    0x002280DA
> 0x0406C: prc1023     (Packets Rx (512-1023B) Count)   0x011AAE56
> 0x04070: prc1522     (Packets Rx (1024-Max) Count)    0x17947F30
> 0x04074: gprc        (Good Packets Received Count)    0x2FA5AB2D
> 0x04078: bprc        (Broadcast Packets Rx Count)     0x00087B79
> 0x0407C: mprc        (Multicast Packets Rx Count)     0x00012C8C
> 0x04080: gptc        (Good Packets Transmitted Count) 0x5BE95883
> 0x04088: gorcl       (Good Octets Rx Count Low)       0xE9E2F9E4
959c959
< 0x04090: gotcl       (Good Octets Tx Count Low)       0x4E694ED0
---
> 0x04090: gotcl       (Good Octets Tx Count Low)       0x4E7EC1B2
976c976
< 0x040C0: torl        (Total Octets Rx Count Low)      0xE9D04842
---
> 0x040C0: torl        (Total Octets Rx Count Low)      0xE9E5F8B6
978c978
< 0x040D0: tpr         (Total Packets Received)         0x2FA5AADE
---
> 0x040D0: tpr         (Total Packets Received)         0x2FA5B373
980,987c980,987
< 0x040D8: ptc64       (Packets Tx (64B) Count)         0x018F18A2
< 0x040DC: ptc127      (Packets Tx (65-127B) Count)     0x03725BF6
< 0x040E0: ptc255      (Packets Tx (128-255B) Count)    0x003EE0ED
< 0x040E4: ptc511      (Packets Tx (256-511B) Count)    0x0023D18D
< 0x040E8: ptc1023     (Packets Tx (512-1023B) Count)   0x14F09ABF
< 0x040EC: ptc1522     (Packets Tx (1024-Max) Count)    0x41948FDD
< 0x040F0: mptc        (Multicast Packets Tx Count)     0x000158F4
< 0x040F4: bptc        (Broadcast Packets Tx Count)     0x0003082C
---
> 0x040D8: ptc64       (Packets Tx (64B) Count)         0x018F1A34
> 0x040DC: ptc127      (Packets Tx (65-127B) Count)     0x03725CD9
> 0x040E0: ptc255      (Packets Tx (128-255B) Count)    0x003EE10B
> 0x040E4: ptc511      (Packets Tx (256-511B) Count)    0x0023D1A7
> 0x040E8: ptc1023     (Packets Tx (512-1023B) Count)   0x14F09ACC
> 0x040EC: ptc1522     (Packets Tx (1024-Max) Count)    0x419493F8
> 0x040F0: mptc        (Multicast Packets Tx Count)     0x000158F7
> 0x040F4: bptc        (Broadcast Packets Tx Count)     0x0003082E
989c989
< 0x01030: qprc00      (Queue Packets Rx Count 00)      0x2FA5A23B
---
> 0x01030: qprc00      (Queue Packets Rx Count 00)      0x2FA5AAD0
1005c1005
< 0x06030: qptc00      (Queue Packets Tx Count 00)      0x5BE951AC
---
> 0x06030: qptc00      (Queue Packets Tx Count 00)      0x5BE95881
1021c1021
< 0x01034: qbrc00      (Queue Bytes Rx Count 00)        0x2B367A72
---
> 0x01034: qbrc00      (Queue Bytes Rx Count 00)        0x2B4C0892
1037c1037
< 0x06034: qbtc00      (Queue Bytes Tx Count 00)        0xD56ADC09
---
> 0x06034: qbtc00      (Queue Bytes Tx Count 00)        0xD5802A3E
> Blockquote
```

Comment: OK... It seems to do the same with the i210 NICs too... but I never noticed it !

`
# ifconfig -a enp35s0 | grep dropped
  RX errors 0  dropped 5118  overruns 0  frame 0
`

So the problem may not be the cards...

Comment: Check the output of the `ethtool -S enp1s0f0` command (or paste it into the question).

Comment: Maybe these packets you cannot see in the tcpdump/wireshark due by frames have being dropped in hardware, without passing to driver. Also check the nic registers content with `ethtool -d <iface>` command. Names of registers should be clear, but if it isn't, you car read the nic datasheet.

Comment: Added 'ethtool -d' results

Comment: Hi,

After some indeep testing (cross pluging cables and devices, tcpdump, etc...), the conclusion is that I have 2 broadcast packets type flooding the local network :
 - "Broadcom" packets come from the Netgear GS108E switch.
 - "Realtek" (RRCP) packets come from my ISP box (router).

Booth are hardware dropped because of the unknown protocol type.
For more indeep infos, check https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/697/

So... Everything is "normal" !

Comment: Hi. It's very interesting and useful info. Thanks for feedback!